# Remove User from SP Group without being a Full Control User Programmatically C#

Tags: 2013, development, permissions

I have a situation where I am creating a "Secondary Admin" role within a custom project I am building.  I need the second admin to be able to remove a user from a group without giving the permissions within the custom permissions level to do so.  It will add the user just fine because I did give Manage Permissions control to this group, but when I try to remove, I get an access denied error.

All of the abilities for the users, including administrators, I am handling on the back end so users do not have to go into any SharePoint list or admin controls to perform these actions.  Is there a way to get this done without giving the user higher permissions?  I think I am just missing something here.  Here is the code below:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using(SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl)) 
    {
        using(SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            for (int i =0; i < userRequest.Length; i++)
            {                    
                SPGroup spGroup = spWeb.SiteGroups[userRequest.GetValue(i).ToString() + "_Contribute"];
                spGroup.AddUser(selectedUser);  //this works just fine

                try
                {
                    SPGroupCollection userCollection = selectedUser.Groups;
                    foreach(SPGroup group in userCollection)
                    {
                        if(group.Name == spWeb.SiteGroups[userRequest.GetValue(i) + "_Read"].ToString())
                        {
                            group.RemoveUser(selectedUser); //this is where I get Access Denied and a catch in my method if the user is not a Site Admin when the code is ran
                        }
                }
                catch 
                {
                    //the empty catch is just incase the user is not in the Read group and was only given Contribute originally
                }
            }
            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
});
```

It of course works for Site Admins with the same logic.  I have a reason for this in my project, and do not want to give any more privileges to the custom permissions group. I am trying to clean up permissions if a user is upgraded from Read to Contribute on a list that is not inherited from the parent.  This is not a program killer, I just want to make sure all of the permissions are clean since I am doing all the work behind the scenes.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set for SharePoint groups which you want to manage by this Second Admin:

- Group Owner: Second Admin
- Who can edit membership in group: Group Owner

Now this Account have Full Control permissions for this group.

[image]